# How does a spinner know its value?

Tags: android, spinner, rotation

I have a spinner which starts a second activity on a value change. This works good.

After a return everything works fine too. But if I rotate now the mobile the OnItemSelectedListener is called! Why? The spinner should be on position -1. Which means that the callback will not be called.

How does android know which spinner item is selected? I tried to prevend to restore this information by sending the base class the a null value for the savedInstanceState.

Here is some code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    String db=MyDatabase.getData();

    if(db == null)
        db="";
    Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(this, db, "ID", "Name");
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setHint(spinner, "Please select...");
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id2) {
            int id=((SpinnerItem)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getId();
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainMenu.this, Other.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SpinnerItem> {
    private final Context context;
    private String hint;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String input, String key, String value) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, create(input, key, value));
        this.context=context;
    }

    private static SpinnerItem[] create(String input, String key, String value) {
        Vector<SpinnerItem> list=new Vector<SpinnerItem>();
        // fill the list
        return list.toArray(new SpinnerItem[] {});
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // show the hint
        if(position == -1) {
            TextView tv=new TextView(context);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            tv.setText(hint);
            return tv;
        }
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public void setHint(Spinner spinner, String hint) {
        if(spinner.getAdapter() == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Set your adapter first!");
        }
        this.hint=hint;
        try {
            final Method m=AdapterView.class.getDeclaredMethod("setNextSelectedPositionInt", int.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(spinner, -1);

            final Method n=AdapterView.class.getDeclaredMethod("setSelectedPositionInt", int.class);
            n.setAccessible(true);
            n.invoke(spinner, -1);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you ellaborate further, can't get exactly what you want.

Comment: @Lalit Poptani when I return to the first activity and rotate the mobile the `OnItemSelectedListener` is called what I don't want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rotate your device your Activity gets restarted or recreated add this line to your AndroidManifest file in activity tag to avoid it.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you **change the orientation** the `onCreate()` of Activity get Called.

and **by default** as the behaviour of the spinner the method `onItemSelectedListener() get called` of the spinner when ever the activity gets created.

**So this is happening to you in this case**

Solution for such issue is given here [StackOverflow Question's Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738527/getting-an-issue-while-checking-the-dynamically-generated-checkbox-through-list/7738854#7738854) **check how he handled the issue by taking two counters** `checkBoxCounter and checkBoxInitialized` and try to implement same in your case.

Comment: That could work I'll check that. But how can I reset the spinner on rotation? My initial status with the text please select would be enough.

Comment: you can store position in variable and then use spinner method sp.setSelection(position);