# Json android images and text are repeated

Tags: android, json

Json android, I have a json which loads images and text, works perfect, but the imagens do not match the text, imagens repeat bone and also the text, I'm wrong, I'm a newbie

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflator;
    ArrayList<JSONFields> result;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<JSONFields> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.result = result;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Holder holder;
        DownloadImageTask task = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.helper, null);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.textview1 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.descrip = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.descripcion);


            task = new DownloadImageTask(holder.image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        JSONFields fields = new JSONFields();

        fields = result.get(position);
        if (task != null)
            task.execute(fields.getUrl());


        holder.textview1.setText(fields.getName());
        holder.descrip.setText(fields.getDescripcion());



        return convertView;

    }

    public class Holder {
        ImageView image;
        TextView textview1;
        TextView descrip;
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;


        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }

}



import com.ditec.json.data.JSONFields;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String URL = "http://169.254.65.190:5000/fbsharing/7BkWVF6r";
    ListView listview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        GetJSON json = new GetJSON();
        json.execute(URL);

    }

    public class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<JSONFields>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<JSONFields> doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                String url = params[0];
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse response;
                response = client.execute(get);
                InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader;
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                String line;
                String json = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    json += line;
                }

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
                ArrayList<JSONFields> alData = new ArrayList<JSONFields>();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    JSONFields data = new JSONFields();
                    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    data.setUrl(obj.getString("url"));
                    data.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                    data.setDescription(obj.getString("descripcion"));
                    alData.add(data);
                }
                System.out.println("Data returned sucessfully");
                return alData;

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<JSONFields> result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, result);

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }

}



public class JSONFields {

    private String name;
    private String url;
    private String descripcion;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public void setDescription(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Volley library for JSON and also easy implementation for getting an Image. Its very efficient.

Example: http://www.kpbird.com/2013/05/volley-easy-fast-networking-for-android.html

And for ImageDownload is NetworkImageView. : http://www.jayway.com/2013/08/20/volley-networking-for-android/

And its only a few line of code. I use this everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this so post, it addresses the exact problem your having of images not matching your texts (due to the view being reused/recycled while the image is loading).
[Listview with images, but when scroll the List, the images apear in wrong rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935584/listview-with-images-but-when-scroll-the-list-the-images-apear-in-wrong-rows)
A easy fix for this is to use the setTag and getTag on the imageview, to set a string (the url for example) that identifies the image that should go in the imageview, and then check that the tag is still the same when your don't loading the image, catching the case where the imageview (convertview) have been recycled.