# Listview with ImageView position is messed up when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll, imageview, picasso

I have a ListView that has 12 rows. Each row item contains an ImageView and two TextViews. The ImageViews' visibility are all set to INVISIBLE. When I click on a row, I change the visibility of the ImageView to VISIBLE.

So, I click on the first row, and it's ImageView becomes visibile, which is good. However, when I scroll the ListView, I find that other rows' ImageViews become visible as well. I have done a lot of searching and found out that is due to recycling views since I'm using ViewHolder pattern.

I've looked at the following links

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511433/checkboxes-in-a-listview-when-i-select-the-first-it-checks-the-last-and-vice/8511643#8511643)

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738527/getting-an-issue-while-checking-the-dynamically-generated-checkbox-through-list/7738854#7738854)

But have not been able to implement it in my code. I honestly don't know how. Below is my pertinent code

**listview_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/frame_background"
    android:padding="5dp"
    >

    <!-- the innner view - provides the white rectangle -->
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/frame" >

        <!-- the icon view -->
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            />

        <!-- the container view for the title and description -->
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            >

            <!-- the title view -->
            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

            <!-- the description view -->
            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ListViewItem.java**

```
public class ListViewItem {

    public final String title;        // the text for the ListView item title
    public final String description;  // the text for the ListView item description
    public final int drawableRef; //Ref to drawable so Picassco can load it
    public boolean visible;

    public ListViewItem(int drawableRef, String title, String description) {
        this.drawableRef=drawableRef;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean value)
    {
        visible = value;
    }

    public boolean getVisible()
    {
        return visible;
    }
}
```

**ListViewDemoAdapter.java**

```
public class ListViewDemoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem> {


    public ListViewDemoAdapter(Context context, List<ListViewItem> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_item,items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            // inflate the GridView item layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

            // initialize the view holder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
            //viewHolder.ivIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            viewHolder.tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            // recycle the already inflated view
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if(position==ListViewDemoFragment.getSelectedPosition())
        {
            viewHolder.ivIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        // update the item view
        ListViewItem item = getItem(position);
        //viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(item.icon);
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(item.drawableRef).into(viewHolder.ivIcon);
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.title);
        viewHolder.tvDescription.setText(item.description);


        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivIcon;
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvDescription;
    }
}
```

**ListViewDemoFragment.java**

```
public class ListViewDemoFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static List<ListViewItem> mItems;        // ListView items list
    private static int mSelectedItem=-1;
    private static ListViewDemoAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // initialize the items list
        mItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
        Resources resources = getResources();

        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.harley1, "TITLE 1", "DESCRIPTION 1"));
        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.harley2, "TITLE 2", "DESCRIPTION 2"));
        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.harley3, "TITLE 3", "DESCRIPTION 3"));

        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.harley4, "TITLE 4", "DESCRIPTION 4"));
        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.harley5, "TITLE 5", "DESCRIPTION 5"));
        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.harley6, "TITLE 6", "DESCRIPTION 6"));

        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.harley7, "TITLE 7", "DESCRIPTION 7"));
        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.harley8, "TITLE 8", "DESCRIPTION 8"));
        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.harley9, "TITLE 9", "DESCRIPTION 9"));

        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.harley10, "TITLE 10", "DESCRIPTION 10"));
        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.harley11, "TITLE 11", "DESCRIPTION 11"));
        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.harley12, "TITLE 12", "DESCRIPTION 12"));

        // initialize and set the list adapter

        adapter = new ListViewDemoAdapter(getActivity(), mItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // remove the dividers from the ListView of the ListFragment
        getListView().setDivider(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // retrieve theListView item
        ListViewItem item = mItems.get(position);
        mSelectedItem = position;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // do something
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static int getSelectedPosition()
    {
        return mSelectedItem;
    }

    public static List<ListViewItem> getList()
    {
        return mItems;
    }

    public static ListViewDemoAdapter getAdapter()
    {
        return adapter;
    }

}
```

I think I need to modify my ListViewItem.java and my adapter, but am having trouble implementing the solutions I looked at.

**EDIT**

ListViewItem.java

```
 public boolean visible = false;

    public ListViewItem(int drawableRef, String title, String description) {
        //this.icon = Resources.getSystem().getDrawable(drawableRef);
        //this.icon = icon;
        this.drawableRef=drawableRef;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean value)
    {
        visible = value;
    }

    public boolean getVisible()
    {
        return visible;
    }
```

**ListViewDemoFragment onClick method change**

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // retrieve theListView item
    ListViewItem item = mItems.get(position);
    mSelectedItem = position;

    item.setVisible(true);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // do something
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**getView() function change**

```
else {
            // recycle the already inflated view
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListViewItem item = getItem(position);
        if(position==ListViewDemoFragment.getSelectedPosition())
        {
            if(item.getVisible()==true) {
                viewHolder.ivIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        // update the item view

        //viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(item.icon);
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(item.drawableRef).into(viewHolder.ivIcon);
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.title);
        viewHolder.tvDescription.setText(item.description);


        return convertView;
```

Comment: Do you want images that have been set to `visible` to stay visible after they have been scrolled off screen and then back on?

Comment: @steve Yes, I want the images to stay visible after they have been clicked regardless where they are on the screen.

Comment: I would add an attribute to your `ListViewItem` that is something like `boolean imageVisibile = false` and when an item gets clicked you can change it to `true`. Then in your adapter's `getView` method you can check the attribute and toggle the visibility of the `ImageView`

Comment: You would need to take the index of the view that is clicked, retrieve the `ListViewItem` at that index, and switch the `imageVisible` attribute to `true`. Unfortunately I don't have time to mock up code.

Comment: @steve I made the changes you suggested but am still getting the same problem. I have edited my post so you can see what I did.

Comment: @steve Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Because of that, I just had to make a simple change on my edited code to get it working.

Comment: Great! Good luck with your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have having a `boolean visible` to record the status,it's not necessary to do this:

```
if(position==ListViewDemoFragment.getSelectedPosition())
    {
        if(item.getVisible()==true) {
            viewHolder.ivIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Just let the data determine `ImageView`'s visibility. write the code below to your getView

```
ListViewItem item = getItem(position);
if (item.getVisible()) {
    viewHolder.ivIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    viewHolder.ivIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Wow, that worked amazingly. I totally forgot about setting other items Invisible too. This ListView I made was a simplified version of what I wanted to do at work (I have to update visibility of ImageViews in a ListView via OnProgressUpdate). Hopefully, I can follow this and apply something similar there. Thanks a lot.