# Checkbox in listview

Tags: java, android

I would like to set a checkbox in a listview's click-event.
How can I set the right checkbox?

This is my code:

```
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                int position, long id)
        {
                         Checkbox checkbox = ??
                         checkbox.setChecked(true);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738527/getting-an-issue-while-checking-the-dynamically-generated-checkbox-through-list/7738854#7738854

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,JavaCode in Activity:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parentView, View childView, int position, long id)    
    {
         CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) childView.findViewById(R.id.file_checkbox);
         cb.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Second,Do not forget one thing about CheckBox in layout xml, Set android:focusable="false" to checkbox in xml , otherwise listview can`t get click event.

Third,And Most important thing,Because when listview scroll , getView() in adapter will be called unexcepted , the checkbox will be mobified unexcepted , so set checkbox status in getView() is very important , Here is my example in getView():

```
if(mFiles[position].isSeleted){
    checkbox.setChecked(true);
} else {
    checkbox.setChecked(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html
may help u

Comment: Answers that contain only a link are bad answers. When the link goes offline this becomes useless. If you just want to provide a link, post as a comment instead. If you want to post an actual answer, summarize the what the "answer" in the link is and point to it for further information. Apart from that: The content on that site is *very* long. Point to a specific section that answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

you need a custom Adapter base list-view you can get from  :: [**Here**](http://android-vogue.blogspot.com/2011/05/custom-listview-in-android.html)