# Howto show data from Array list to Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contacts

I am working on an application in which i need to fetch all the contacts from the contact book and display. i want the user to select some contacts and add them in a group which is saved in db.

i have created a custom list view- contactitem.xml-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">


 <TextView

    android:id="@+id/contactname"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"        
   android:singleLine="true"
    android:clickable="true"/>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/contactnum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="@color/White"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:text="@string/add_contacts"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

i have a SelectContact class for fetching contacts from Contact book-

```
public class SelectContacts extends Activity implementsOnItemClickListener {

    private List<Contact> list = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    private ListView contact_list;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selectcontacts);
        contact_list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactsListView);
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                    pCur.moveToFirst();
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String number=pCur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        Contact c=new Contact();
                        c.setContactName(name);
                        c.setContactNum(number);
                        list.add(c);
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                }
                ContactAdapter contactAdapter=new ContactAdapter(this, R.layout.contactitem, list);
                contact_list.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

and implemented a custom adapter- ContactAdapter-

```
public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>{

    List<Contact> items;
    LayoutInflater mInflater ; 
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId; 

    public ContactAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Contact> items) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
        this.layoutResourceId=layoutResourceId;
        this.items = items;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        if(row==null){
            mInflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = mInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.contactname);
            holder.number = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.contactnum);
            holder.add=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.add);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        String name=items.get(position).getContactName();
        String number=items.get(position).getContactNum();
        holder.name.setText(name);
        holder.number.setText(number);
        holder.add.setText("Add");
        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView name;
        TextView number;
        Button add;
    }
}
```

here Contact is a simple POJO-

```
public class Contact {
    private String contactName;
    private String contactNum;

    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }
    public void setContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    public String getContactNum() {
        return contactNum;
    }
    public void setContactNum(String contactNum) {
        this.contactNum = contactName;
    }

}
```

i am a newbie in android..

Here when i start SelectContact activity it cannot display contact on the UI.. please help me guys...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will insist you to use `List<Contact> list = new ArrayList<Contact>();` instead of using `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Contact>>   list= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Contact>>();`

You just need to fetch the Contact details and set the values to the `Contact` Class and add to the `ArrayList` object. And then just pass the list Object to ArrayAdapter class and use it. This is the easiest way, you are making it a bit complex using `HashMap` in this case.

Comment: Bro i have changed the Code and but still getting nothing.. I debugged the SelectContact Class. Here it is fetching names but cann't retrieve numbers..

Comment: so you are getting the names in list but not the numbers, is it so?

Comment: no.. i mean to say that i put a toast in the loop to popup the number.. bt it is not displaying any thing.. i think the flow is not reaching in the pCur Loop..

Comment: I checked your code you are having problem in fetching the Contact details and storing in the ArrayList, just check your while loops.

Comment: thanks bro... I have managed loops.. now i can display both name and number.... :)

Comment: @LalitPoptani
i had fetched the contacts & i tried to select multiple contacts but whenever i scroll down or up it automatically deselect the selected contacts & when i deselect the selected contacts manually & scroll down or up it automatically get selected,....\

Comment: This is the problem of Adapter class check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738527/getting-an-issue-while-checking-the-dynamically-generated-checkbox-through-list/7738854#7738854)