# Custom listView multiselection

Tags: android

I am developing Listview where Multiple selection is possible,now the problem is when i scroll down or up the selection of items get lost and selection made on any other item except the selected one.

Below is my Activity.

```
  public class ContactPickerActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<Contact> arr = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    private Context context;
    private ListView list;
    private ContactArrayAdapter adapter;
    private String strName,strNumber;
    private View view;  
    public static ArrayList<Boolean> arrBoolean = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_picker);
        ProgressDialog pd  = new ProgressDialog(this);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactList);
        arr = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        context = ContactPickerActivity.this;
        arr =  displayContacts();
        Log.i("ContactPicker", "Completed Displaying Contact list ::: " + arr.size());
        adapter = new ContactArrayAdapter(this,arr);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
//              list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
//                      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listContent));
        list.setOnItemClickListener(ContactSelectedListener);
        Log.i("Boolaean >>> ", arrBoolean.size() + "");


    }

    private OnItemClickListener ContactSelectedListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
            Log.i("ListViewTest","Item Click");
            SparseBooleanArray checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                Log.i("ListViewTest", arr.get(i)+ ": " + checked.get(i));
            }
        }
    };

    private ArrayList<Contact> displayContacts() {

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
        Contact contact;
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                contact = new Contact();
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People.DISPLAY_NAME));
                contact.setName(name);
                arr.add(contact);
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
********* Adapter *****

public class ContactArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

//  private final List<Contact> list;
    private Context context;    

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Contact> list; 

     public ContactArrayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Contact> arrPublicData) {

        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.list = arrPublicData;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (view == null) {         
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.multiselect_row, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkItem);

            viewHolder.checkbox
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    Contact element = (Contact) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                    element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                    ContactPickerActivity.arrBoolean.add(buttonView.isChecked());
                    Log.i("Boolaean 123 >>> ", buttonView.isChecked() + "");
                }
            });
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());        
        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}
```

i m not able to get Items checked....
Any Help is appericiated...Thanx in Advance

Comment: this is because of listview is created again and again, i also faced this problem

Comment: what solution do u get ?

Comment: [Solution is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738527/getting-an-issue-while-checking-the-dynamically-generated-checkbox-through-list/7738854#7738854).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your getView method, please correct this as follows:

```
    public class ContactPickerActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<Contacts> arr = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
    private Context context;
    private ListView list;
    private ContactArrayAdapter adapter;
    private String strName,strNumber;
    private View view;  
    public static boolean[] arrBoolean = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        //setContentView(R.layout.contact_picker);
        ProgressDialog pd  = new ProgressDialog(this);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactList);
        arr = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        context = ContactPickerActivity.this;
        arr =  displayContacts();
        arrBoolean=new boolean[arr.size()];
        Arrays.fill(arrBoolean, false);
        Log.i("ContactPicker", "Completed Displaying Contact list ::: " + arr.size());
        adapter = new ContactArrayAdapter(this,arr);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
//              list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
//                      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listContent));
        list.setOnItemClickListener(ContactSelectedListener);
        Log.i("Boolaean >>> ", arrBoolean.size() + "");


    }

    private OnItemClickListener ContactSelectedListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
            Log.i("ListViewTest","Item Click");
            arrBoolean[position]=!arrBoolean[position];
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    private ArrayList<Contacts> displayContacts() {

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
        Contacts contact;
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                contact = new Contacts();
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People.DISPLAY_NAME));
                contact.setName(name);
                arr.add(contact);
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
//********* Adapter *****

public class ContactArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

//  private final List<Contact> list;
    private Context context;    

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Contacts> list; 

     public ContactArrayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Contact> arrPublicData) {

        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.list = arrPublicData;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (view == null) {         
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.multiselect_row, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkItem);


            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(ContactPickerActivity.arrBoolean[position]);        
        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}
```

Comment: @jeet can you please post working code, the arrBoolean.set has error

Answer (score 5):

http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/custom-listview-ability-check-items/

check this

Edited

```
holder.chkField.setChecked(true);
holder.chkField.setTag(R.id.chkItem, position);
check.add(position, true);
```

You need to change this as

```
if(check.getAt(position)){ 
   holder.chkField.setChecked(true);
}else{
   holder.chkField.setChecked(false);
}
holder.chkField.setTag(R.id.chkItem, position);
```

Put below line in Check listener on checked condition put true or false

```
check.add(position, isChecked);
```

Answer (score 2):

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<String> arrPublicData;    
private int checkCount = 0;
private ArrayList<Boolean> check = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

 public ListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> arrPublicData) {

    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arrPublicData = arrPublicData;
    checkCount = arrPublicData == null ? 0 : arrPublicData.size();
}

public int getCount() {
    return arrPublicData.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null) {
        rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.multiselect_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.txtField = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
        holder.chkField = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.chkItem);
        holder.chkField.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener);
        holder.chkField.setChecked(true);
        holder.chkField.setTag(R.id.chkItem, position);
        check.add(position, true);      
        rowView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtField.setText(arrPublicData.get(position));    
    if(check.get(position) == true)
    {
       holder.chkField.setText(arrPublicData.get(position));    
    }
    else
    {
       holder.chkField.setText(arrPublicData.get(position));    
    }       

    return rowView;
}
```

class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtField;
    CheckBox chkField;
}

I think you are not checking condition whether checkbox is checked or not so your checkbox get change when you scroll your listview hope that will help

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because you have inflated a checkBox with same id multiple times. So modify your code in following way,

1. Add a **TableRow/LinearLayout** in Xml in the place of **checkBox**.
2. in the `getView` method create a CheckBox at run time and set its ID as the **position** (list position) and add it to the TableRow/LinearLayout in xml using `addView()` method.
3. now if the problem still persists,  In **CheckChanged Listener** create Vector and add the position of checked items in the vector and while creating checkBox have a check on the Vector if the current view position is checked then use `setChecked(true)` method to check it.

may be i'm not clear but i don't know a better way to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample program, in which I am setting background color of the view according to state of the row, just change changing backgrouund code to check state;

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
    private String[] arrItems={"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
    private boolean[] arrState={false, false, false, false, false};
    private ListView lv;
    private ArrAdapter adapter;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTest);
        adapter=new ArrAdapter(this);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                arrState[position]=!arrState[position];
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

    private class ArrAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
        Context mContext=null;
        public ArrAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, R.layout.row);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            mContext=context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arrItems.length;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi=convertView;
            ViewHolder holder=null;
            if(vi==null)
            {
                vi=LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
                holder=new ViewHolder();
                holder.mTxt=(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                vi.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
                holder=(ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            holder.mTxt.setText(arrItems[position]);
            if(arrState[position])
                vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            else
                vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }


        private class ViewHolder
        {
            TextView mTxt=null;
        }


    }

    private void clear()
    {
        Arrays.fill(arrState, false);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```