# How tell which widget is pressed in a custom list adapter?

Tags: android, list, widget

I have a custom list adapter that has a ToggleButton in the xml for each of the list items, so this is an example of two items in the list:

[image]

I used a link, as I do not have enough reputation to post pictures. The irrelevant parts are blurred out. For the layout for each list item, the ToggleButton has the id "toggleButton1" but this is a problem, as in the onClick function I made called "onTogglePress()" it always references the first one when I use `ToggleButton activetoggle = (ToggleButton)this.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);` to get information about the toggle button, such as if it isChecked() or not. How can I target each list item individually that way I can use the toggle presses to change information relevant to the actual list item it is on?

EDIT: Here is my getView() class from my custom list adapter as requested:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView; //this is listview_item_row

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ListHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.txtTime = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
            holder.txtDays = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtDays);
            holder.txtVibrate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtVibrate);
            holder.activButton = (ToggleButton)row.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ListHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        ListObject currentobj = storagelist.returnSchedule(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(currentobj.returnName());
        holder.txtTime.setText(currentobj.timestostring());
        holder.txtDays.setText(currentobj.daystostring());
        holder.txtVibrate.setText(currentobj.vibratetostring());
        holder.activButton.setChecked(currentobj.isActive());

        Typeface customfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
        holder.txtTitle.setTypeface(customfont);
        holder.txtTime.setTypeface(customfont);
        holder.txtDays.setTypeface(customfont);
        holder.txtVibrate.setTypeface(customfont);


        if(currentobj.returnVibrate())
            holder.txtVibrate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#35b4e3"));    //green
        else
            holder.txtVibrate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8C8C8C"));        //red

        return row;
    }
```

Comment: How do you create the layout for each row in your listview?

Comment: Using CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), 
                R.layout.listview_item_row, mainObjectList);, where R.layout.listview_item_row is the layout, the mainObjectList is the object array that holds the information for each item in the list, and CustomListAdapter is my custom list adapter class.

Comment: post your getView() method from your Adapter.

Comment: In your CustomListAdapter, you should set the OnClickListener for the button in each row as they are inflated. You can do this in `newView()` and umm...the other method you have to override.

Comment: check if button is clciked check if poisition is zero then proceed to do wat you want to do.

Comment: @Code-Guru: How do I do this? I have the method for when the toggleButton is clicked as onTogglePress() defined in xml as android:onClick="onTogglePress" but this has to be a public method in my class that contains the activity by default, which at that point I've lost a reference to which list item it was

Comment: @Raghunandan: The problem is the position is contained in the getView but the method for recieving the toggle clicks is in my main class, which has no reference to the position of the item

Comment: Start with following FoamyGuy's request.

Comment: can u post your main class code.

Comment: All compund buttons (in particular ToggleButton) has it's listener OnCheckedChangedListener, try to override it with togg.setOnCheckedChangedListener().

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306726/the-oncheckchanged-listener-works-only-for-the-first-checkbox-in-a-customlistvie is related.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out! You may want to post the info as a an answer rather than just an edit to your question. Also you can give more details than just the link to help others who may have a similar problem in the future. Good luck with your app.

Comment: @Code-Guru: I will here in 7 hours when it lets me, I have to wait 8 hours due to low reputation. And thank you!