# Data in listview is being shifted from top row to bottom row on the focus change

Tags: android, listview

I'm using a listview which has text view and edittext. I'm controlling the data in it through `ViewHolder`. The problem is that when I write the data in first column and second as so on the portion visible on screen and when scroll it the data from first row is  copied to the last row automatically.

Here is the code:

```
private class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    ViewHolder holder;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList values;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList values)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.taskstrt, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        System.out.println("in mobile constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.taskstrt, parent, false);
            holder.editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setText(values.get(position).toString());
        holder.textView.setId(position);
        holder.editText.setId(position);
        holder.editText.setFocusable(false);
        // holder.editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        holder.editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                final int positio = v.getId();
                edittexthold = (EditText) v;
                textholder = (TextView) v;
                edittexthold.setFocusable(true);

                if (edittexthold.getText().toString().length() > 0)

                {
                    HashMap<Integer, String> Map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                    Map.put(positio, edittexthold.getText().toString());

                    data.set(positio, Map);
                    System.out.println(data);
                }

                System.out.println(positio + " this is position that is clicked");
                if (positio == 4)
                {
                    System.out.println("going to assign ID");
                    qq = positio;
                    showDialog(NAME_LIST);
                }

                if (positio == 5)
                {
                    qq = positio;
                    System.out.println("going to start time ID");
                    showDialog(STARTTIME);
                }

                if (positio == 3)
                {
                    qq = positio;
                    System.out.println("going to date picker ID");
                    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                }
            }
        }) ;
        holder.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
        {

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
            {
                //if(!hasFocus)
                {
                    final int positio = v.getId();
                    String conv = null;
                    final EditText edittexthold = (EditText) v;
                    final TextView textholder = (TextView) v;
                    edittexthold.setFocusable(true);

                    if (edittexthold.getText().toString().length() > 0)

                    {
                        HashMap<Integer, String> Map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                        Map.put(positio, edittexthold.getText().toString());

                        data.set(positio, Map);
                        System.out.println(data);
                    }

                    edittexthold.setFocusable(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7738854/726863

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please try this code it may help you

```
private class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{

     ViewHolder holder;
            private Context context;
            private ArrayList values;

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList values)
            {

                super(context, R.layout.taskstrt, values);
                this.context = context;
                this.values = values;
                System.out.println("in mobile constructor");



            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.taskstrt, parent, false);

               if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {

                     holder = new ViewHolder();



                    holder.editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

         holder.textView.setText(values.get(position).toString());

                    holder.textView.setId(position);
                    holder.editText.setId(position);
                    holder.editText.setFocusable(false);
                   // holder.editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

                    holder.editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {




                        public void onClick(View v) {



                            final int positio = v.getId();
                             edittexthold = (EditText) v;
                             textholder = (TextView) v;
                             edittexthold.setFocusable(true);

                             if(edittexthold.getText().toString().length()>0)

                             {  HashMap<Integer, String> Map=new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                                    Map.put(positio, edittexthold.getText().toString());

                                    data.set(positio, Map);
                                    System.out.println(data);
                                }

                            System.out.println(positio+" this is position that is clicked");
                            if(positio==4)
                            {
                                System.out.println("going to assign ID");
                                qq=positio;
                                showDialog(NAME_LIST);


                            }

                            if(positio==5)
                            {
                                qq=positio;
                                System.out.println("going to start time ID");
                            showDialog(STARTTIME);
                            }

                            if(positio==3)
                                {
                                qq=positio;
                                System.out.println("going to date picker ID");
                                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                                }







                        }
                    }) ;
                    holder.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
                    {

                    //if(!hasFocus)
                        {


                        final int positio = v.getId();
                        String conv=null;
                        final EditText edittexthold = (EditText) v;
                        final TextView textholder = (TextView) v;
                        edittexthold.setFocusable(true);

                         if(edittexthold.getText().toString().length()>0)

                         {  HashMap<Integer, String> Map=new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                                Map.put(positio, edittexthold.getText().toString());

                                data.set(positio, Map);
                                System.out.println(data);
                            }

                         edittexthold.setFocusable(false);
                    }   }
                });


                    convertView.setTag(holder);

                }
```

Comment: This Code has solved that problem by now what is happening that when i scroll back to aboveto see what i have written it is deleted.

Comment: After adding convertview.setTag(holder); the data is not beinng copied but above row which is typed is been deleted ??