# Android:Gallery App shows images at wrong place when scrolled in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

Well, I have been making a Gallery App for android for a while. I've used ViewHolder to prevent lag while scrolling. However, when I scroll back up, the images above are replaced by other images. After a while, the original images are displayed in the Grid. Why does this happen? Also, how can I fix this problem?

Another question, how do other Gallery Apps display images? Do they use ViewHolder as well?

Any Help would be highly appreciated.

Here is my MainActivity class:

```
package com.example.om.imageviewer3;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    AsyncTaskLoadFiles myAsyncTaskLoadFiles;

    public class AsyncTaskLoadFiles extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

        File targetDirector;
        ImageAdapter myTaskAdapter;

        public AsyncTaskLoadFiles(ImageAdapter adapter) {
            myTaskAdapter = adapter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

            String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/DCIM/Camera/";
            targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
            myTaskAdapter.clear();

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
            Arrays.sort(files);
            for (File file : files) {
                publishProgress(file.getAbsolutePath());
                if (isCancelled()) break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            myTaskAdapter.add(values[0]);
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            myTaskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;
        ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        void add(String path) {
            itemList.add(path);
        }

        void clear() {
            itemList.clear();
        }

        void remove(int index){
            itemList.remove(index);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return itemList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return itemList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        //getView load bitmap ui thread
  /*
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ImageView imageView;
   if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
          // attributes
    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 220));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
   } else {
    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
   }

   Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 220,
     220);

   imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
   return imageView;
  }
  */

        //getView load bitmap in AsyncTask
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                // attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220,250));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

                convertView = imageView;

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.image = imageView;
                holder.position = position;
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                //imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                ((ImageView)convertView).setImageBitmap(null);
            }

            //Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 220, 220);
            // Using an AsyncTask to load the slow images in a background thread
            new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap>() {
                private ViewHolder v;

                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
                    v = params[0];
                    Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 500, 500);
                    return bm;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    //Not work for me!
           /*
           if (v.position == position) {
               // If this item hasn't been recycled already, 
            // show the image
               v.image.setImageBitmap(result);
           }
           */

                    v.image.setImageBitmap(result);

                }
            }.execute(holder);

            //imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            //return imageView;
            return convertView;
        }

        public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth,
                                                 int reqHeight) {

            Bitmap bm = null;
            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                    reqHeight);

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

            return bm;
        }

        public int calculateInSampleSize(

                BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            // Raw height and width of image
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
                if (width > height) {
                    inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height
                            / (float) reqHeight);
                } else {
                    inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
                }
            }

            return inSampleSize;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            ImageView image;
            int position;
        }

    }

    ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);

  /*
   * Move to asyncTaskLoadFiles String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath =
   * Environment .getExternalStorageDirectory() .getAbsolutePath();
   * 
   * String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/test/";
   * 
   * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath,
   * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); File targetDirector = new
   * File(targetPath);
   * 
   * File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles(); for (File file : files){
   * myImageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath()); }
   */
        myAsyncTaskLoadFiles = new AsyncTaskLoadFiles(myImageAdapter);
        myAsyncTaskLoadFiles.execute();

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(myOnItemClickListener);

        Button buttonReload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reload);
        buttonReload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                //Cancel the previous running task, if exist.
                myAsyncTaskLoadFiles.cancel(true);

                //new another ImageAdapter, to prevent the adapter have
                //mixed files
                myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this);
                gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);
                myAsyncTaskLoadFiles = new AsyncTaskLoadFiles(myImageAdapter);
                myAsyncTaskLoadFiles.execute();
            }});

    }

    OnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            String prompt = "remove " + (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), prompt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            myImageAdapter.remove(position);
            myImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };

}
```

Update:Here's the code(it lags a lot)

```
package com.example.om.imageviewer4;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    AsyncTaskLoadFiles myAsyncTaskLoadFiles;

    public class AsyncTaskLoadFiles extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

        File targetDirector;
        ImageAdapter myTaskAdapter;

        public AsyncTaskLoadFiles(ImageAdapter adapter) {
            myTaskAdapter = adapter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

            String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/DCIM/Camera/";
            targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
            myTaskAdapter.clear();

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
            Arrays.sort(files);
            for (File file : files) {
                publishProgress(file.getAbsolutePath());
                if (isCancelled()) break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            myTaskAdapter.add(values[0]);
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            myTaskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;
        ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        void add(String path) {
            itemList.add(path);
        }

        void clear() {
            itemList.clear();
        }

        void remove(int index){
            itemList.remove(index);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return itemList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return itemList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        //getView load bitmap ui thread
  /*
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ImageView imageView;
   if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
          // attributes
    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 220));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
   } else {
    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
   }

   Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 220,
     220);

   imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
   return imageView;
  }
  */

        //getView load bitmap in AsyncTask
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;

            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                // attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 220));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

                convertView = imageView;

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.image = imageView;
                holder.position = position;
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                //imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                holder.position=position;
                ((ImageView)convertView).setImageBitmap(null);
            }


            //Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 220, 220);
            // Using an AsyncTask to load the slow images in a background thread
            new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap>() {
                private ViewHolder v;
                private String path=holder.toString();

                /*@Override
                protected void onPreExecute(){
                    path=v.image.getTag().toString();
                }*/

                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
                    v = params[0];
                    //path=v.image.getTag().toString();
                    Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 220, 220);
                    return bm;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    //Not work for me!

                    //Toast.makeText(mContext,"WTF: "+v.image.getTag().toString()+"\n"+holder.image.getTag().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if(!v.image.getTag().toString().equals(path)){
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Here3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    if(result!=null && v.image!=null && v.position==position){
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"HereUP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        v.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        v.image.setImageBitmap(result);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Here",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        v.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    //v.image.setImageBitmap(result);

                }
            }.execute(holder);

            //imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            //return imageView;
            return convertView;
        }

        public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth,
                                                 int reqHeight) {

            Bitmap bm = null;
            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                    reqHeight);

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

            return bm;
        }

        public int calculateInSampleSize(

                BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            // Raw height and width of image
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
                if (width > height) {
                    inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height
                            / (float) reqHeight);
                } else {
                    inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
                }
            }

            return inSampleSize;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            ImageView image;
            int position;
        }

    }

    ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);

  /*
   * Move to asyncTaskLoadFiles String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath =
   * Environment .getExternalStorageDirectory() .getAbsolutePath();
   * 
   * String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/test/";
   * 
   * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath,
   * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); File targetDirector = new
   * File(targetPath);
   * 
   * File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles(); for (File file : files){
   * myImageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath()); }
   */
        myAsyncTaskLoadFiles = new AsyncTaskLoadFiles(myImageAdapter);
        myAsyncTaskLoadFiles.execute();

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(myOnItemClickListener);


    }

    OnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            String prompt = "remove " + (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), prompt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            myImageAdapter.remove(position);
            myImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };

}
```

Comment: It's obviously a view recycling issue, look for similar answers regarding ListView, btw, seperate the Async.

Comment: Ya, I know, i tried if(v.position==position) but it did not work for me. Any other ideas? Also, I didn't understand what you mean by Separating the Async.

Comment: the call to the Async inside getView - it's a mess, I would rewrite - not the functionality per say, but the syntax, for an example which could shed some light [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738527/getting-an-issue-while-checking-the-dynamically-generated-checkbox-through-list), ofcourse there are more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to check if this view is already in use for another position, but you also need to change position each time in your holder.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 250));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            ViewHolder dataHolder = new ViewHolder();
            dataHolder.image = imageView;
            imageView.setTag(dataHolder);
            convertView = imageView;
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(null);
        holder.position = position; // <-- this line

        new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap>() {
            private ViewHolder v;

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
                v = params[0];
                Bitmap bm=decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 500, 500);
                return bm;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                if (position == v.position) // <-- this line
                    v.image.setImageBitmap(result); // <-- this line
            }
        }.execute(holder);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: My Girlfriend's gonna kill me but, what the hell, Marry me.

Comment: Hey, the above solution worked perfectly. However, whenever I scroll really fast, the image loading is slow. I guess this is because AsyncTask is still loading the earlier images and later realises the View has changed. How do I get around this problem?

I tried a little with setVisibility function of imageView but didn't get anywhere close. Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, i usually end up building some image HashMap cache, but you have to control its size and probably even create algorithm clearing some part of this cache if it has too many images... But this will not help you much on fast scrolling for the first time you see an image. I'm not sure right now how you can solve this, because you can't interrupt `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);` if it's already started

Comment: Well, I got an idea. What if we load the images only when the user stops scrolls. Any idea to implement that? I'm sure it'll work better. Like, we could stop loading more images if the user flicks. And then continue loading images at thr current view once it stops...